# Questons about finding limit from sequence topic

Tags: sequences-and-series

P1: lim as n goes to infnity $(2^{n} + 3^{n} )^{1/n}$

P2: lim as n goes to infnity $((2/1) . (3/2) . (4/3) . ...(n+1/n) )^{1/n}$

P3: lim as n goes to infnity $( 1 + 2^{1/n} + 3^{1/n} ...n^{1/n} )^{1/n}$

Comment: Write some of your thinking on these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\left(2^n+3^n\right)^{1/n}=3\left(1+\left(\frac23\right)^n\right)^{1/n}$$

$$\frac21\frac32\frac43\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{n+1}n=n+1$$

$$n\le1+2^{1/n}+3^{1/n}+\ldots+n^{1/n}\le n\,3^{1/n}$$